# phpexcel not converting my html table tag

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

This is my code using **phpexcel**

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $message);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Sheet 1');

/*header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');*/

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('Test.xls');
```

I commented the header because it downloads using browser.

$message contains

```
 <style>
                    .td_font{

                        display: block;
                        line-height:1px;
                    }
                    .header{
                        font-size:0.8em;
                        display: block;
                        text-align:center;
                        font-weight:bolder;
                    }

    </style>
                    <table rules='all' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse; display:block;' >
                         <tr>
                              <td width='5%' class='header'>NO.</td>
                              <td width='35%' class='header'>HARDWARE TYPE</td>
                              <td width='35%' class='header'>HW NAME</td>
                              <td width='25%' class='header'>BARCODE</td>
                         </tr></table>`
```

When it outputs. It just print my html tags literally. Is it possible in phpexcel to interpret my html tags of table as a table and save it in excel?

Comment: Save the "message" as a file to disk, then use the HTML Reader.... but otherwise HTML markup is simply a string as far as PHPExcel is concerned

Comment: Oh I see. in phpexcel he looks at html simply as a string. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks